# Why css transition is not working?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

So I'm trying to put a hover for an image block but the transition is not working, i have no clue why this is happening. 

This is the HTML:

```
 <div class="area">
      <div class="mask"></div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
```

This is the CSS: (cursor is working well but the transitions are not working at all)

```
.area {
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
}

.area:hover .mask{
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.mask{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(226,23,37,0.9);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: what property are you trying to animate? `display` doesn't make sense and that is the only one you have on both classes

Comment: display: none in the third selector wouldn't show the red background until someone hovers on it, and im just trying to make transition when hover occurs

Comment: if cursor is working, I think the whole css code is working but just "position:absolute" make the mask invisble. you can check it using inspect element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `display:none` from `.mask` and move `background-color: rgba(226,23,37,0.9);` to the `.area:hover .mask` rule:

```css
.area {
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
}

.area:hover .mask{
    cursor: pointer;
 background-color: rgba(226,23,37,0.9);
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.mask{
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
    <div class="mask"></div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
```

Comment: No problem @user2522053